# Reading XML with jQuery and AJAX Unsuccessful

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, xml

I've been trying to load an XML into a standalone HTML page. Since I'm working with standalone computers as well, I have neither internet connection nor a server for the files, so obviously XMLHttpRequest doesn't work. I've read here that I can use jQuery AJAX to load the XML into the HTML, but for some reason it won't load the information stored on it, even if I use codes I've found here.

I've downloaded a jQuery library from the jQuery site, and based on what I found here the code looks something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "myXML.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            var myXML = $(xml).data();
        }
    });
});
```

When for the time being I'm just trying to read the data, not use it. myXML doesn't have much data to begin with as well at the moment (like I said, the actual XML is on a standalone), so this is how it looks:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<type>
    <type id="1">
        <model> Lenovo </model>
        <year> 2015 </year>
    </type>

    <type id="2">
        <model> iPhone </model>
        <year> 2014 </year>
    </type>
</type>
```

Not only the code doesn't work, the HTML page also ignores every script written afterwards, including alert() or write(). Does anybody have a solution to that?

Comment: does the script reference added before writing script ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function readXML() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "myXML.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (xml) {
            var typeArr = $(xml).children(); //give you type id array
            var id=typeArr[0].attr('id'); // 1
            var type_0_childern =  typeArr[0].childern(); 
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: It certainly recognises the script now, thanks! But for some reason I still can't access the information. How do I do that?